# Function to Generate Random Coordinate Points Python

Tags: python

I am trying to create a function which will give me 70 random coordinate points. This is the code I have now:

```
# Generate test data
points = []
for _ in range(70):
    x = random()
    y = random()
    points.append((x, y))
    print(points)
```

but the code I have creates an output such as:
[(0.4107139467174139, 0.3864211980981259)]
[(0.4107139467174139, 0.3864211980981259), (0.6159949847158482, 0.6526570064673685)]
[(0.4107139467174139, 0.3864211980981259), (0.6159949847158482, 0.6526570064673685), (0.6515694521853568, 0.9651948000023821)]
...

I have also tried:

```
# Generate test data
cord_set = []
for _ in range(70):
    x = random()
    y = random()
    cord_set.append((x, y))
    print(cord_set)
```

With similar results.

Comment: Ok, what don't you like about what it's generating? What's your _expected range_? And which `random()` are you even calling? The title of your question isn't even a question - try rephrasing it to state what specifically is wrong. See [ask]

Comment: @msanford I want an output such as (x1, y1), (x2, y2), etc. It doesn't have to be within a specific range.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the comment section, you mentioned that you just want an output like  (x1, y1), (x2, y2), the reason why you are getting this many of list is because in the loop, you print the list points in every iteration. Just remove the print statement out of the loop should give you the output you want.

```
points = []
for _ in range(70):
    x = random()
    y = random()
    points.append((x, y))
print(points)
```

Based on your comment, I think you are saying for every iteration, you want the result to be [(x,y)] which is a list. If so, you need to have a temp list to pass those generated value:

```
points = []
for _ in range(70):
    single_point = []
    x = random()
    y = random()
    single_point.append((x, y))
    points.append(single_point)
print(points)
```

This gives you [[(x1,y1)],[(x2,y2)],...]

If that is the case, I don't think you will need the () to make it nested. You can just go with:

```
points = []
for _ in range(70):
    single_point = []
    x = random()
    y = random()
    single_point.append(x)
    single_point.append(y)
    points.append(single_point)
print(points)
```

This gives you [[x1,y1],[x2,y2]...]

Comment: Just wait till he figures out he's getting the same 2 points over and over...

Comment: @Zichezeng Unfortunately I need the output to look like: [(x1, y1)]
[(x2, y2][(x3, y3)] ... instead of [(x1, y1)]
[(x2, y2), (x3, y3)]
[(x4, y4), (x5, y5), (x6, x6)]